# Parsing double quote from csv using jackson-dataformat-csv

Tags: java, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a csv that contains the following

```
EANHotelID|SequenceNumber|Name|Address1|Address2|City|StateProvince|PostalCode|Country|Latitude|Longitude|AirportCode|PropertyCategory|PropertyCurrency|StarRating|Confidence|SupplierType|Location|ChainCodeID|RegionID|HighRate|LowRate|CheckInTime|CheckOutTime
541454|99999999|Hotel Maan Residency|"B" Wing, Gopal Palace, opp. ocean park|Naherunagar-Satellite Road|Ahmedabad||380 015|IN|23.02266|72.53842|AMD|1|INR|3.0||ESR|Near Kankaria Lake|||0|0|10:00 AM|10:00 AM
```

Now I'm trying to read each row in this csv as an object using the following code

```
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();

    File csvFile = new File("D:\\ActivePropertyList.txt.bak2");

    CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader().withColumnSeparator('|').withNullValue("");
    MappingIterator<Map<String,String>> it = mapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(schema)
                .readValues(csvFile);

    while (it.hasNextValue()) {
        Map<String,String> value = it.nextValue();
    }
```

But it's failing because of the `"B"` that exists in the csv. I get the following error:

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected
>   character ('W' (code 87)): Expected separator ('"' (code 34)) or
>   end-of-line  at [Source:
>   (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader); line: 2,
>   column: 43]

How can I parse the double quotes in the csv correctly? I tried playing around with `schema.withEscapeChar()` `schema.withQuoteChar()` but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I managed to solve it by using `withoutQuoteChar()` on the schema. Although I don't have a proper explanation of whats happening under the hood. If anyone can shed some light it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `withoutQuoteChar()` on the schema to handle double quotations in the csv content, i.e.

```
CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader().withColumnSeparator('|').withNullValue("").withoutQuoteChar();
```